# Nginx-redis module returning string length along with the value from Redis

Tags: nginx, redis, openresty

I am using [redis2-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module) to serve html content stored as a value in `redis`. Following is the `nginx` config code to get value for a key from redis.

```
  redis2_query get $fullkey;                                     
  redis2_pass     localhost:6379;                                
  #default_type text/html;
```

When the url is hit the following unwanted response is rendered along with the value for that key.

```
$14
```

How to remove this unwanted output? Also if key passed as an argument doesn't exist in the redis, how to check this condition and display some default page?

Answer (score 0):

(Here's [a similar question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/593669/nginx-httpredis2module-get-value-only))

There's no way with just redis2 module, as it [always return a raw Redis response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/openresty-en/N8eHtJb17ew/kJgg-OYGMwEJ).

If you only need `GET` and `SET` commands you may try with HttpRedisModule (`redis_pass`). If you need something fancier, like hashes, you should probably try [filtering the raw response from Redis with Lua](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module#lua-interoperability), e.g. something along the lines of

```
content_by_lua '
    local res = ngx.location.capture("/redis",
        { args = { key = ngx.var.fullkey } }
    )
    local body = res.body
    local s, e = string.find(body, "\r\n", 1, true)
    ngx.print(string.sub(body, e + 1))
';
```

(Sorry, the code's untested, don't have an OpenResty instance at hand.)

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I couldn't find any installation guide for lua-resty-redis. Can you suggest me some blogpost or installation instruction?

Comment: Sorry, don't have any. When I had experimented with nginx+Lua I've basically built nginx with `--add-module=path/to/lua-module` among the other options, in a same manner [official docs suggest](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#installation).

Comment: Can you help out in this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480357/404-page-not-found-when-a-url-is-hit-but-properly-served-when-opened-from-the-li